# Invite Facebook's friends from own website

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

When someone visits my web page, I would like to enable him to share the visited web page on his facebook friend's wall, so that other people can also click on the shared link to come on the visited webpage.
Condition: The visited webpage should appear on the facebook wall of selected friends and I would like to throw an user-id with the link so that when someone clicks on the link on facebook wall, when he comes on the web page I can identify who did share the web page by his user-id.

I did try: the facebook send button, link button, send dialog and feed dialog, but somehow none of these meet the requirements above. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: Do you want the user to share link on his wall or his friend's wall?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you looking for? ->https://floating-headland-9554.herokuapp.com

i created a invite friend button at the page for me to send request to my facebook to like my page.

you can view source and get my code, it all javascript integrated.

regards,
woolei - facebook application consultant
website - www.wootube.woolei.com